# Get all dates after current date CakePHP

Tags: date, cakephp

I have a question i want to get all the dates after the current date.

I use this code for that but it don't work.. can someone help me.

```
public function index() {
        $this->loadModel('wp_em_events');

        $date = date('d-m-Y');


        $this->set('wp_em_events',$this->wp_em_events->find('all', array(

            'conditions' => array(
                'wp_em_events.event_start_time >=' => date('Y-m'),
            )
        )));
    }
```

Comment: Is the format of your database field `event_start_time` the same as `date('Y-m')` ?  Is your `$model->name` really `wp_em_events`?

Comment: its like tis 2014-01-20 @J_B so date(Y-m-d) and yes the model name is like that :P because its a external wordpress database.

Comment: Seems `>= date('Y-m')` should work.. perhaps turn on debug mode in `core.php` and view the SQL query dump.  Look at the actual query that it is running.  Does this find return anything??

Comment: I get this `wp_em_events` AS `wp_em_events` WHERE `event_start_time` >= '2014-07-02'

Comment: Why do you set ``$date`` in your code if you're not using it? Can you supply the field definition of ``event_start_time`` and some sample data with a manual query that works? Finally, you can name your model ``WpEvent`` or just ``Event`` and have it point to the ``wp_em_events`` table. The way you have it doesn't follow conventions.

Comment: Hii @user221931 here is a link to the site http://nielsvandijkje.nl/demo/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment pointing to site [nielsvandijkje.nl/demo](http://nielsvandijkje.nl/demo) doesn't reply how field `event_start_time` is defined in the db.

Still in your demo results are:

```
2014-07-04
2   Traditional music session   2013-02-17
3   6 Nations, Italy VS Ireland     2014-01-20

Query
SELECT [...] WHERE `event_start_time` >= '2014-07-04'
```

Since results with date 2013-02-17 and 2014-01-20 are returned it means that most probably the field isn't defined as a `date` and the db tries to compare strings which will [fail to produce correct results](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/using-date.html).

So this doesn't seem like a cakephp issue but a DB issue. You can confirm it by running the raw SQL in phpmyadmin or mysql's CLI which should yield the same (wrong) results.

Comment: I see my mistake :P i was using the wrong field! event_start_time = event_start_date! Thanks for the support Guys

Answer (score 1):

get all result whose date_updated is less then current date.

```
$result = $this->TableModel->find('all');
$result->where(['DATE(date_updates) <'=>date('Y-m-d')]);
```